# How do you add a permission to a cmake target without repeating the default permissions?

Tags: cmake

I would like to turn on the `setuid` bit for a program I'm installing using [`install(TARGETS...`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html) in `cmake`.

I can do this using the `PERMISSIONS` clause and specify `SETUID`. But when I do this, I lose all the default permissions unless I specify all of those, too.

For example, if this were bash, it would be like running `chmod u=s,g=,o= file` instead of `chmod u+s file` -- all the existing permissions are turned off instead of just masking in the one permission you want to add.

Is there a mechanism in `cmake` to add a permission to an installed target without repeating all the default permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake has no other ways for set permissions for installed files except PERMISSIONS option for `install` command. But there are many ways for simplify permissions settings.

For example, you can define variable, contained default permissions set:

```
set(PROGRAM_PERMISSIONS_DEFAULT
    OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ OWNER_EXECUTE
    GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE
    WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE)
```

and use it as base for add new permissions:

```
install(TARGETS myexe ... PERMISSIONS ${PROGRAM_PERMISSIONS_DEFAULT} SETUID)
```

If some set of permissions is used in many places, you can define variable, contained that set, and use it when needed:

```
set(PROGRAM_PERMISSIONS_BY_ROOT ${PROGRAM_PERMISSIONS_DEFAULT} SETUID)
...
install(TARGETS myexe ... PERMISSIONS ${PROGRAM_PERMISSIONS_BY_ROOT})
```